# c++ file handling - class objects

Tags: c++

The following code read 3 obj and write them into a file.
however im unable to retrieve objects properly using the below code.
data is duplicated and is not in order

plz help

old code :

```
#include<fstream.h>
#include<conio.h>

class mail
{
  public:
    char un[25];             // user name
    char pd[25];             // passsword

    void reg(int);

} obj[5];

void mail::reg(int k)
{
  int i;
  i=k;

  clrscr();
  cout<<"Enter user name ( enter unique name )\n";
  cin>>un;


  cout<<"Enter password\n";
  cin>>pd;

  ofstream filout;
  filout.open("email",ios::app||ios::binary);
  if(!filout)
  {
    cout<<"cannot open file\n";
  }
  else
  {
    cout<<"\n "<<i;
    filout.write((char *)&obj[i],sizeof(mail));
    filout.close();
  }

  cout<<"You are now registered. \n";
  getch();

}        // end of sign up or register func

void main()
{

  int t;
  clrscr();
  obj[0].reg(0);
  obj[1].reg(1);
  obj[2].reg(2);

  mail obj2;

  ifstream filein;
  filein.open("email",ios::in||ios::binary);
  if(!filein)
  {
    cout<<"Unable to open file to read\n";
  }
  else
  {
    while(!filein.eof())
    {

      filein.read((char *)&obj2,sizeof(obj2));

      cout<<"username "<<obj2.un<<" passwword "<<obj2.pd<<"\n";
    }
    filein.close();
  }
  getch();

}
```

Also please tell me how to put code into stackoverflow. Manually putting 4 spaces after copy pasting is very tiresome

new code after making changes :

```
#include<fstream.h>
#include<conio.h>

struct mail
{
    char un[25];             // user name
    char pd[25];             // passsword
    void reg(int);
} obj[5];

void mail::reg(int k)
{
    int i=k;
    clrscr();
    cout<<"Enter user name ( enter unique name )\n";
    cin>>un;
    cout<<"Enter password\n";
    cin>>pd;

    ofstream filout;
    filout.open("email",ios::app|ios::binary);
    if(!filout) {
        cout<<"cannot open file\n";
    } else {
        cout<<"\n "<<i;
        filout.write((char *)&obj[i],sizeof(mail));
        filout.close();
    }

    cout<<"You are now registered. \n";
    getch();

}   // end of sign up or register func

int main()
{
    int t;
    clrscr();
    obj[0].reg(0);
    obj[1].reg(1);
    obj[2].reg(2);

    mail obj2;

    ifstream filein;
    filein.open("email",ios::in|ios::binary);
    if(!filein) {
        cout<<"Unable to open file to read\n";
    } else {
        while(filein) {
            filein.read((char *)&obj2,sizeof(obj2));

            cout<<"username "<<obj2.un<<" passwword "<<obj2.pd<<"\n";
        }
        filein.close();
    }
    getch();
}
```

Im still facing problem. I write 3 object. But iam getting 4 output records. Last one is duplicated.

Comment: Copy paste the code, highlight it and hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: never `void main`, main always returns int. Remove all of your extra spaces also to make things easier to read.

Comment: Never use `eof()`. It's not correct.

Comment: `ios::in||ios::binary` should be `ios::in|ios::binary`,  these flags are bitwise-or'd  together, not logically-or'd

Comment: Look again at Need4Sleep's answer: you don't check whether `filein` is good between the read and the print. The state doesn't become bad when you read the last element (that worked ok), but when you _try_ (and fail) to read another element that isn't there. In that case, read fails and you print the un-changed value of `obj2`.

Comment: Thanks. Im really stupid

Answer (score 2):

You have an improper file loop, an EOF() loop is bad practice and often can lead to undefined behavior, a proper loop would be as follows:

```
filein.read((char *)&obj2,sizeof(obj2));
while(filein)
{
    cout<<"username "<<obj2.un<<" passwword "<<obj2.pd<<"\n";
    filein.read((char *)&obj2,sizeof(obj2));
}
```

the structure of this loop allows the file to check the file for EOF before reading again, while the eof loop will read the eof in THEN check, leading to some junk at the end.

- your fileIn variable uses improper flags, you use '`||`' the logical OR
  operator instead of the '`|`' logical bitwise operator. This could be a
  possible reason for your error.
- you have some issues with your program, `void main()` make most
  people here cringe, main ALWAYS returns `int`

Comment: `while (filein)` is as bad as `while(!filein.eof())`

Comment: how would you correctly structure a file loop? I've never had any issues using this method for months now.

Comment: Its much better. But im still facing problem plz see updated qn

Comment: @Need4Sleep Take [this example code](http://ideone.com/DlEL1P) and make **test.txt** 4 bytes long. The output I get is 2, which is clearly wrong. The problem with your loop is that it makes a read, but it doesn't check if read was succesful - much like the `while(!f.eof())` version. The correct form would be f.ex. `while (filein.read((char *)&obj2,sizeof(obj2))`.